# texture painting acting up and painting in other places than where stencil is

Tags: modeling, texture-painting, cloth-simulation

I am following a tutorial here --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKa06EwFuJk&t=632s

When I apply paint the face on, It's stretching the paint down the object where I'm not even painting at. If I move the face up the body to the top of the head, then the paint will paint right, but I don't need the face on the forehead of the ghost.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: how does your UV map look like? also check the normals

Comment: That little white box in the right corner is the UV editor if that's what your talking about. And when you say normals do you mean the auto smooth for the normals in the object data properties??

Comment: maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Sorry, I forget to do that. https://pasteall.org/blend/e19531198f5f40b588978b08bab80027 does the blend file come with the image I'm using for the face within the file itself, or should I send you the link to that image? Also ignore the bones, I'm trying to see if I can make the arms move with bones for animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UV unwrap is bad, look, I've selected all these faces and their UVs are overlapping in the *UV Editor*, you need to unwrap again, if you plan to paint in the 3D view you can simply unwrap with the *Smart UV Project* mode.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, do you know what may have caused my problem, so I can look out for that in the future. I did everything that was done in the tutorial, so I'm not sure why it messed up on mine.

Comment: you must have made a mistake when you unwrapped but I can't tell what mistake, maybe see some tutorials on unwrapping to understand it better?